# Responsive Text Issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I have the following code:

```css
body{
    width:100%;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    background: transparent;  
}
.testimonials{
    margin:0;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit,minmax(350px, 1fr));
    grid-gap:20px;
}
.testimonials .card{
    position:relative;
    width:350px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:#333;
    padding:20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow: 10px 8px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    overflow: hidden;
}
.testimonials .card .layer{
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(100% - 3px);
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    background:linear-gradient(#034e70, #390375);
    z-index:1;
    transition:0.5s;
}
.testimonials .card:hover .layer{
    top:0;
}
.testimonials .card .content{
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}
.testimonials .card .content p{
    font-size:18px;
    line-height:24px;
    color:#FFF;
}
@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
.testimonials .card .content p{
width: 100%;
}
}

.testimonials .card .content .image{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius:50%;
    overflow:hidden;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba{0,0,0, .2};
}
.testimonials .card .content .details h2{
    font-size:15px;
    color:#fff;
}
.testimonials .card .content .details h2 span{
    color:#03a9f4;
    font-size:12px;
    transition:0.5s;
}
.testimonials .card:hover .content .details h2 span{
    color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<section id="References">
      <div class="section-title">
        <h2>References</h2>
        </div>
    <div class="testimonials">
    <!-- CARD 1 START-->
    <div class="card">
      <div class="layer"></div>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vulputate dui a eros pretium commodo sit amet quis tortor. Maecenas suscipit suscipit est non ullamcorper. Fusce tincidunt, eros non ornare mollis, enim erat placerat erat, dignissim egestas magna elit eget dolor. Nullam sed leo maximus, ullamcorper ante lacinia, semper augue. Etiam convallis tempus elit.</p>
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://static-exp1.licdn.com/sc/h/244xhbkr7g40x6bsu4gi6q4ry" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="details">
          <h2>
            Sample Text <br>
            <span>Sample Text Goes Here Too</span>            
          </h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- CARD 1 end-->
    
    <!-- CARD 2 START-->
    <div class="card">
      <div class="layer"></div>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vulputate dui a eros pretium commodo sit amet quis tortor. Maecenas suscipit suscipit est non ullamcorper. Fusce tincidunt, eros non ornare mollis, enim erat placerat erat, dignissim egestas magna elit eget dolor. Nullam sed leo maximus, ullamcorper ante lacinia, semper augue. Etiam convallis tempus elit.</p>
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://static-exp1.licdn.com/sc/h/244xhbkr7g40x6bsu4gi6q4ry" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="details">
          <h2>
            Sample Text <br>
            <span>Sample Text Goes Here Too</span>           
          </h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- CARD 2 end-->
    <!-- CARD 3 START-->
    <div class="card">
      <div class="layer"></div>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vulputate dui a eros pretium commodo sit amet quis tortor. Maecenas suscipit suscipit est non ullamcorper. Fusce tincidunt, eros non ornare mollis, enim erat placerat erat, dignissim egestas magna elit eget dolor. Nullam sed leo maximus, ullamcorper ante lacinia, semper augue. Etiam convallis tempus elit.</p>
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://static-exp1.licdn.com/sc/h/244xhbkr7g40x6bsu4gi6q4ry" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="details">
          <h2>
           Sample Text <br>
            <span>Sample Text Goes Here Too</span>            
          </h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- CARD 3 end-->
  </div>
</section>
```

I have the above code embedded in a website and so when I view the website on a smaller screen, I am getting this output:

[image]

The white text, image, and blue text are not responsive. However, the card is. Its just these three things, and I tried adding media queries to make them responsive but it did not work for some reason, and the output was the exact same as above.

### Expected Output

[image]

When I inspect it and view it on 414 width, I am getting the above expected output **which is what I want**. However, below 414 width, I am getting the output as shown in the very first picture. How would I fix this? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating the `grid-template-columns` on media query for responsive design/mobile screen.

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: transparent;
  margin: 0;
}

.testimonials {
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(350px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.testimonials .card {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 350px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #333;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 10px 8px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.testimonials .card .layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% - 3px);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(#034e70, #390375);
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.testimonials .card:hover .layer {
  top: 0;
}

.testimonials .card .content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.testimonials .card .content p {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #FFF;
}

.testimonials .card .content .image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.testimonials .card .content .details h2 {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

.testimonials .card .content .details h2 span {
  color: #03a9f4;
  font-size: 12px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.testimonials .card:hover .content .details h2 span {
  color: #fff;
}

@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
  .testimonials {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100%, 1fr));
  }
  .testimonials .card .content p {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="References">
  <div class="section-title">
    <h2>References</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="testimonials">
    <!-- CARD 1 START-->
    <div class="card">
      <div class="layer"></div>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vulputate dui a eros pretium commodo sit amet quis tortor. Maecenas suscipit suscipit est non ullamcorper. Fusce tincidunt, eros non ornare mollis, enim erat placerat erat, dignissim
          egestas magna elit eget dolor. Nullam sed leo maximus, ullamcorper ante lacinia, semper augue. Etiam convallis tempus elit.</p>
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://static-exp1.licdn.com/sc/h/244xhbkr7g40x6bsu4gi6q4ry" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="details">
          <h2>
            Sample Text <br>
            <span>Sample Text Goes Here Too</span>
          </h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- CARD 1 end-->

    <!-- CARD 2 START-->
    <div class="card">
      <div class="layer"></div>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vulputate dui a eros pretium commodo sit amet quis tortor. Maecenas suscipit suscipit est non ullamcorper. Fusce tincidunt, eros non ornare mollis, enim erat placerat erat, dignissim
          egestas magna elit eget dolor. Nullam sed leo maximus, ullamcorper ante lacinia, semper augue. Etiam convallis tempus elit.</p>
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://static-exp1.licdn.com/sc/h/244xhbkr7g40x6bsu4gi6q4ry" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="details">
          <h2>
            Sample Text <br>
            <span>Sample Text Goes Here Too</span>
          </h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- CARD 2 end-->
    <!-- CARD 3 START-->
    <div class="card">
      <div class="layer"></div>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vulputate dui a eros pretium commodo sit amet quis tortor. Maecenas suscipit suscipit est non ullamcorper. Fusce tincidunt, eros non ornare mollis, enim erat placerat erat, dignissim
          egestas magna elit eget dolor. Nullam sed leo maximus, ullamcorper ante lacinia, semper augue. Etiam convallis tempus elit.</p>
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://static-exp1.licdn.com/sc/h/244xhbkr7g40x6bsu4gi6q4ry" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="details">
          <h2>
            Sample Text <br>
            <span>Sample Text Goes Here Too</span>
          </h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- CARD 3 end-->
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you've set a fixed `width` of `350px` for your element. When you make the window any smaller than ~370px wide, the fixed width prevents the element from getting any smaller. Try using relative sizes like `%` instead.

Comment: its not min-width though, its just `width`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Same deal tho.

Comment: So in your opinion, what should I set it to?

Comment: Try something like... `85%` for the width.

Comment: You also have a fixed width per column on your grid. You may want to alter that with a @media query.